# Fading an MKCircleView

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation

I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of why my MKCircleViews aren't responding to this animation call:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddOverlayViews:(NSArray *)overlayViews
{
    MKOverlayView *oV; 
    for (oV in overlayViews) 
    {
        //fade in radius view
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeIn" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        oV.alpha = 0.5;
        [UIView commitAnimations];    
    }  
}
```

What is happening is that they are simply appearing at 0.5 alpha without any animation at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to animate the MKCircleView, check this out.

There's something hidden of the MKOverlayView and its subclass which some of the operations on UIView doesn't work well on it (as least it seems to me). However, the following approach should give you what you need.

http://yickhong-ios.blogspot.com/2012/04/animated-circle-on-mkmapview.html